# opensnoop with follow children mode

Tags: dtrace

`opensnoop` from `DTrace` can show which files are opened by a program/pid. It does not trace opens by forked/vforked children though. Related `dtruss` has this follow functionality.

Is there a way to tell `opensnoop` to also follow children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-p` option actually adds `PID == pid` check into generated script where `pid` is [`built in variable`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/819-5488/gcfpz.html), representing current process id and `PID` is a `-p` option value.

There is an action in DTrace called [`progenyof`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E53395/gkwzq.html) which checks that current process is a child (not necessary direct) of a process, so simply replace that check in opensnoop:

```
--- /usr/dtrace/DTT/opensnoop   Wed Jun 25 01:34:47 2014
+++ opensnoop   Fri Jan 13 17:43:41 2017
@@ -199,7 +199,7 @@

        /* check each filter */
        (OPT_name == 1 && NAME == execname) ? self->ok = 1 : 1;
-       (OPT_pid == 1 && PID == pid) ? self->ok = 1 : 1;
+       (OPT_pid == 1 && progenyof(PID)) ? self->ok = 1 : 1;
        /* OPT_file is checked on return to ensure pathp is mapped */
}
```